# Como recibir datos usando Socket en Android

Tags: android, socket

Estoy tratando de hacer una app para recibir datos en mi dispositivo Android, pero lo lo estoy logrando, no recibí nada, por favor alguien me puede decir cual es mi error o cómo conseguir esto.

Este es mi codigo:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mbuttonWiFiOnOff = (Button)findViewById( R.id.bt1_buttomWifiOnOff) ;
    mbuttonLed2 = (Button)findViewById( R.id.bt3_buttonLed2) ;
    mSendButton = (Button)findViewById( R.id.bt2_SendButton) ;
    mTextoEditor1 = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.et1_WriteValues) ;
    mDumpTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tv1_ReadValues) ;
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sc1_Scroller);

    l1=l2=l3=enable_WIFI=true;
    context=this;

    turnOnOffWifi(context, enable_WIFI);
    enable_WIFI = true;

    mbuttonWiFiOnOff.setText("WIFI OFF");
    mbuttonLed2.setText("Led2 OFF");

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    Thread myThread = new Thread( new MyServerThread ());
    myThread.start();

}

    public class MyServerThread implements Runnable{
       private final static String SERVER_ADDRESS = "192.168.4.1";
       private final static int SERVER_PORT = 8888;

    public void run(){
        InetAddress serverAddr;
        DatagramPacket packet;
        DatagramSocket socket;
        try {
            serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_ADDRESS);
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
            socket.receive(packet );
            String bufferRXD = new String( buf.toString());
            Log.e( "DEBUG-->", "Datos: " + bufferRXD );

            mDumpTextView.append( bufferRXD );
            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo( 0, mDumpTextView.getBottom() );

            socket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



    public void wifi_connect(View v){
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(enable_WIFI){
        turnOnOffWifi(context, enable_WIFI);
        enable_WIFI=false;

        mbuttonWiFiOnOff.setText("WIFI ON");

        Toasty.success(this, "WIFI Conectado!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

        conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
        conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
        conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        int netid= wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(netid, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
    } else {
        turnOnOffWifi(context, enable_WIFI);
        enable_WIFI = true;

        mbuttonWiFiOnOff.setText("WIFI OFF");
        Toasty.error(this, "WIFI Desconectado!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que sucede? ¿Se muestra algo en el LogCat ?, Por cierto no es recomendable usar :  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);     te sugiero usar un Asynctask

Comment: El problema es que no hay data recibido